# Let anonymous users upload files to my Google Drive using the Google Drive SDK

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm building a web app where I need to let users upload files. I want to store the files uploaded by all the users in 'my' central Google Drive. The users shouldn't have to login to their Google Accounts or authorize the app, because they will be uploading to my Google Drive. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use service accounts to store files on behalf of your application:

https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts

Comment: Very nice info, thank you. One thing, what may be inportant from here: "Service accounts are accounts associated with a service or a project. They do not belong to a user and can only be accessed programmatically by the associated application."