# Getting Server Rejected error when upload using Google Picker, Oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

We are trying to use `google.picker` to have our users upload files to **our** drive account (i.e., the user is not required to have a Google account to upload).

We're trying to [use regular Google accounts as application-owned accounts](https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts#use_regular_google_accounts_as_application-owned_accounts) and got our `AUTH_TOKEN` using OAuth2 and set it using  `.setOAuthToken(AUTH_TOKEN)` .  We followed everything described in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/).

However, when uploading, we got a `Server Rejected` error.  The call to `https://docs.google.com/upload/resumableupload?authuser=undefined` returned:

> {"errorMessage":{"reason":"REQUEST_REJECTED","additionalInfo":{"uploader_service.GoogleRupioAdditionalInfo":{"completionInfo":{"status":"REJECTED"},"requestRejectedInfo":{"reasonDescription":"agent_rejected"}}},"upload_id":"AEnB2Ur64Gb0JDCk_8mg5EhpdcaqL82wBQHumHjcGvDqYibtksmUzhfhBolsmBFzRuvQPRyi43SYfactJZvIWYrQ6xAqzu3L9g"}}

We know we cannot use [service accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269201/let-anonymous-users-upload-files-to-my-google-drive-using-the-google-drive-sdk) since the picker doesn't support it.

Do we miss something in getting the `AUTH_TOKEN`?  Do we need to something in the console?

Comment: Why have you got authuser=undefined? What is that for? Are you actually using the auth token?

Comment: Ali, we are using the token.  The call to the url above is made by the picker internally. I also am not sure why the parameter `authuser=undefined`.  I just placed it here because this is the call that returned the error above.

Comment: Have you solved it? If so, please post your solution here - I have exactly the same problem right now.

Comment: If the user does not have a Google account, who is authorizing the access to whose account?

Comment: Can you show the code making the request and if possible the redirect URIs and origin URIs from the api credentials may be error is with the hosts trying to authenticate

Comment: Are you able to make, with other scopes perhaps, other Google API calls for other services (e.g. calendar?). Being able to do that would signal that the issue isn't token-related.

Answer (score 1):

### Give us a little more code, or check the call to gapi.auth.authorize()

1. Check that you are using the correct scope to obtain the OAuth token.

   - Scope should be https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
2. Double-Check the scope declaration:

   - https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#sendauthrequest
3. Check the call to `gapi.auth.authorize()`

   ```
   window.gapi.auth.authorize(
   {
        'client_id': clientId,
        'scope': scope,
        'immediate': false
   },
   handleAuthResult);
   ```

   from: https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#hiworld

Without an actual code sample, it is very difficult to say exactly what is going on. Most likely it is the auth token colection. However, it may also be something as simple as not defining a google User (clientID) which in turn impacts the `gapi.auth.authorize()` call.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this thread can help you: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-Picker-API/PPd0GEESO78
It is about setting the oauth context

or this one:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/drive/GDl4uBkkbxM/jRejcxI-EV8J
It is about the type of file you try to upload with autoconvert on..

Answer (score 0):

Use a Google Apps script on Drive with the function doPost to send data to the server. Then write to file with the Drive API. On publish, you have to set the permissions to "accessible to anyone, even anonomous" if doing cross-domain calls. Make the script run under your user name in Google (for testing), but most likely you would want that function moved onto some application-user account in Gmail.

If you need a level of authentication involved, even if the script is made public, you may authenticate against a CloudSQL hosted database and/or with the Jdbc library to connect to an external resource.

Answer (score 0):

The Scope seems to be the problem.OAuth Token must be obtained using correct scope only:
http://tinyurl.com/ldotq4y

Answer (score 0):

Easily replace `scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'` to `scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'` . So that you're allow to make change including upload something to your Google Drive account.