# Upload file by guest user to my google drive using php

Tags: php, file, upload, google-drive-api

I am trying to integrate file uploading option for guest users to my google drive using php. But while run the code, it is asking for my google user name and password.
How to avoid that and without login via google account, user can upload file to my google drive.
I am following the same steps as mentioned in `https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js`
I have checked the post `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269201/let-anonymous-users-upload-files-to-my-google-drive-using-the-google-drive-sdk` but unfortunately the page is not opening right now.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-a-background-web-app-without-user-intervention-canonical?s=8|2.2559

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I go through your post but did not understand the last point:
Copy the returned Refresh Token and paste it into your app, source code or in to some form of storage from where your app can retrieve it.
Where I need to copy and paste the refresh token? Please let me know.